# Oracle Equivalent of the following SQL Server syntax

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I'm looking for the Oracle equivalent of the following SQL Server syntax:

```
select Cast(0x41424344 as varchar(max))
```

In SQL Server, it selects  'ABCD'.

`0x41424344` is the hex of 'ABCD'

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: In SQL Server, it selects 'ABCD'. 0x41424344 is the Hex of 'ABCD'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SQL> select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2('41424344') from dual;

UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2('41424344')
------------------------------------
ABCD
```